# Is this a key change? (Radiohead:Creep)

Tags: key

The chords for Radiohead's Creep follow this pattern: G Bm C Cm

My question is whether the C->Cm constitutes a change of key and if so which keys are being used and why does this 'work'?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unconventional use of iv and I7 chords](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/60538/unconventional-use-of-iv-and-i7-chords)

Comment: It looks like the `Cm` chord is a minor iv chord in the key of `G`. This might make the question a duplicate of the question I've linked to above.

Answer (score 4):

No key change. Cm is from the *parallel* key of G minor, a common borrowing. It's not even considered a modulation.

Comment: Brilliant. Thanks for clearing that up. Now you've given me the terminology Google has expanded on your answer by pointing me to [Wikipedia's Borrowed Chord Article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borrowed_chord)

Answer (score 2):

The second chord is actually B *major*, acting as secondary dominant to E minor. However the E minor is avoided via [deceptive motion](http://dictionary.onmusic.org/terms/1034-deceptive_cadence) to C major.  Depending on who you ask, this is either a modulation or it isn't, but there is certainly an accidental (the D sharp).

After the C major comes a C minor which is acting as minor subdominant of G to set up [plagal motion](http://openmusictheory.com/popRockHarmony-plagal.html) back to G.

So there is continuous tension between the keys of G major and its relative minor, E minor. Even though there isn't a single E minor chord in the song. Nifty, huh? I love Radiohead.

Comment: Well spotted on B maj. Modulations take on the mantle of a new key, albeit for a short while. There's no indication in this situation that it's moving away from G (maj or min), so it can't be called a modulation - by anyone who understands...and as you state, the mod would be into Emin (at that point) which we never get to see. But going to Cm won't constitute a mod either.